# 'outlined' not working in Material UI Select

Tags: css, reactjs, select, drop-down-menu, material-design

I am implementing Material UI `Select' for which values are coming from backend. Below is my code

```
<FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
  <InputLabel ref={inputLabel} id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label" htmlFor="outlined-Name">
                                    Name
  </InputLabel>
  <Select
    value={Name}
    onChange={handleChange}
    labelWidth={labelWidth}
    inputProps={{
      name: 'Name',
      id: 'outlined-Name',
   }}
>
 <MenuItem value="1" className={classes.menuItm}>All</MenuItem>
   {
     NameArr.data.map(Name => (
     <MenuItem value={Name.name} className={classes.menuItm}>{Name.name}</MenuItem>
 ))
   }
</Select>      
</FormControl>
```

The problem with below code is that `variant="outlined"` is not getting applied. I am not able to see the outline/border which should be there as per the demo here https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-9jyoj
What's wrong in my code?

Comment: I am not pro of react i am using angular but it seems form your code that you were using `variant="outlined"`  on wrong place that should be on `<TextField` as mention in their doc https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/. As using this on  `<FormControl` didn't style that because its skip its style hierarchy

Comment: Your code is ok, outlined is applied. https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-tfquc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `@material-ui/core` package.
In the current version (`4.9.1`) `outlined` is passed properly to the `<FormControl>` children.

For me personally an update from `4.1.0` to `4.9.1` fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you should apply outline variant to select like so :

```
<FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
  <InputLabel ref={inputLabel} id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label" htmlFor="outlined-Name">
                                    Name
  </InputLabel>
  <Select
    value={Name}
    variant="outlined"    {/*  -------------> here is what you looking for */}
    onChange={handleChange}
    labelWidth={labelWidth}
    inputProps={{
      name: 'Name',
      id: 'outlined-Name',
   }}
>
 {NameArr.data.map(Name => (
     <MenuItem value={Name.name} className={classes.menuItm}>{Name.name}} 
     </MenuItem>
  )}
</Select>      
</FormControl>
```